# Laravel 404 Error won't work

Tags: php, laravel-4, http-status-code-404, wamp

Im trying to set up a 404 page for my laravel website; for what I've been reading I should add

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('error.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

to the app/start/global.php file. But the problem is as soon as I add this to the file and I go to a route that doesn't excist I get the following message: Error in exception handler.

I did add a map error in my views and created a view missing.blade.php in there!

I've been trying a lot of stuff but can't solve the problrem till now.

Atm I'm running the project on WAMP.

Hope somebody can help me out with this! :)

What my laravel logs:

```
> [2014-12-22 15:10:54] production.ERROR: exception
> 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in
> C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php:5687
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(5004):
> Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #1 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(4992):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #2 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(4984):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #3 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(717):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #4 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(698):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #5 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(7706):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> 1, true)
> #6 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(8309):
> Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> 1, true)
> #7 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(8256):
> Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1,
> true)
> #8 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(10895):
> Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1,
> true)
> #9 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\bootstrap\compiled.php(659):
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #10 C:\Users\Sam\Dropbox\Web Projects\Petere\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
> #11 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Does your `laravel.log` contain anything?

Comment: You should have a `views/error/missing.blade.php` file. What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: I added the log I get and @DamienPirsy reread my post both ur answers are in there. I did at the file and the only thing I get is: Error in exception handler.

Comment: You wrote `a view missing.blade.php`, which is different from `error/missing.blade.php`.Anyway

Comment: I did place the view missing.blade.php inside a faolder named error. That should be right ?

Comment: That should be right yes. Can you make sure the view really works? Just use a route or controller that works and return `Response::view('error.missing');`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `404.blade.php` in your views `resources/views/error/404.blade.php` it will work like what I did.